# How to use SonarQube quality gates to control your TFS build for Java project build by Maven task

Tags: sonarqube

Is very easy to integrate SonarQube quality gates to control your TFS builds for .NET project build by MSbuild as described here: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/02/11/use-sonarqube-quality-gates-to-control-your-visual-studio-team-services-builds/
this is only one checkbox.
How I can do the same for Java project which is build by Maven Task 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/08/the-maven-build-task-now-simplifies-sonarqube-analysis/
I couldn't find respective checkbox

Comment: Please update your question to 1.) make it more readable and 2.) elaborate on what exactly you are looking to get help with. When reworking your question, reference the formatting guide (http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and a community style guide (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 0):

the same problem for me...

Here is a solution: 
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Breaking+the+CI+Build